# why when I do logout the cookie is not destroyed?

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, jwt, mern

I have this logout controller it should destroy the cookie it worked in postman fine but in client side when I dispatched and hit logout button the token is still in the network storage and I can make requests with it also when I reload the page user get logged in again

**authController**

```
const logoutUser =  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  // Clear the token cookie by setting it to null and expiring it immediately
  res.cookie("token", null, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now()),
    httpOnly: true,
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Logged Out",
  });

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Logged Out" });
});
```

**userAction**

```
// Logout User Action
export const logoutUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await axios.get(`${API_URL}/auth/logout`);
    dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER_SUCCESS });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_USER_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
};
```

**logout**

```
const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logoutUser()); 
    navigate('/')// Dispatch the logout action when the logout button is clicked
  };
```

I tried removing the cookie from the application storage by setting it to null and expiring it using *js* but this only worked in localhost because he I deployed the project on vercel the cookie is not shown in the cookie storage it only sent with the request and can only access it from the network pannel so there is no way to manage it from clientside.

Comment: I guess you should destroy cookies with `clearCookie`. Check this https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie